# no of ways to pick k objects from n and put them in p available spots.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose if there are n people and 2 seats to be filled, and I choose 3 people out of the n. In how many ways can these 3 people then take the two seats, given they are chosen out of the n people.

Comment: Can you tell the difference in between the two spots? Can the spots be empty at the end?

Comment: So any of the three can take the first seat, and any of the remaining two can take the second seat. and no the spots cannot be empty.

Comment: So $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 2.$ One chooses first the two people, and then distribute them in the seats.

Comment: so what happens if there are n people and I choose the 3 out of n first, and fill the two seats using those 3 people i picked?

Comment: Well you are just left with **choosing** the $3$ people out of $n.$ In how many ways can you do this? Multiply that by the problem above and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ummm... your problem effectively starts once the three people are chosen.  So what does $n$ have to do with anything?